# c# winform screen resolution

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a C# WinForms application and when I give the executable to different users the application displays in different sizes (based on their screen resolution). Some of the parts of the application can't be seen.

how can I set absolute 1280X800 for my forms and make sure that the form size will not be changed whatever resolution is!

Comment: You can set minimum size, but if there isn't enough screen space then the window will extend beyond the visible display. I would advise you make use of the `Anchor` property for controls, and use scroll panels where required... just wait until one of your users decides they want to change the DPI setting, that will be even more fun!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Control.ScaleControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.scalecontrol.aspx) and [Control.Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158413.aspx)

```
private void MainForm_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    float width_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1280);
    float heigh_ratio = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 800f);

    SizeF scale = new SizeF(width_ratio, heigh_ratio);

    this.Scale(scale);

   //And for font size
   foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
   {
      control.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", c.Font.SizeInPoints * heigh_ratio * width_ratio);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is why I love and miss WPF/WinForms :( It's sooooo amazingly... packed with features and C#...OH C#! Oh...just...love that C#!

Answer (score 3):

Use the MaximumSize property of the form.

`form.MaximumSize = new Size(1280, 800);`

You can also set a MinimumSize if you don't want the user to make it smaller than a desired size.

Answer (score 2):

You can instead design the GUI so it scrolls up and down more easily.You can make use of the following

[Layout Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx)

[Docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The property

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

is very useful for form sizing and positioning. For example this code:

```
this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width/2;
this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height/2;
this.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top + Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height)/4;
this.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left + Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width)/4;
```

will place the form in which it is executed in the middle of the screen and size it to half the screen.

The WorkingArea var is used to exclude stuff like the task bar and other docked items on the desktop when calculating the size of the screen.

Hope this helps.